# ng-click and child selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an owl carousel that doesn't fire events on the cloned items. 
So, [as solution people propose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749209/owl-carousel-2-cloned-item-click-events-not-firing) to move the event from direct target to its parent one:

from:

```
$('#multiple-carousel .item').click(function () {
        alert("click");
});
```

to:

```
$('#multiple-carousel').on('click', '.item', function () {
    alert("click");
});
```

Could I similarly change from my code:

```
<div id="multiple-carousel">
   <div class="item" ng-click="myClick($event)">...</div>
</div>
```

to something like:

```
<div id="multiple-carousel" ng-click[???".item"???]="myClick($event)??">
   <div class="item" >...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using `ng-repeat` for the slider items by any chance?

Comment: no, I use server side foreach

Comment: Can you include part of code you use to generate items (server-side foreach)? You return HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter in jquery's .on is the filter which descendants will trigger the event, however, events in AngularJS are usually handled via directives ( ng-click in this case ) which do not support the same functionality as jQuery does.

You can add click event with `angular.element`, however if you want to use directive ( which is the right thing to do ), you have to do something like this:

```
$scope.myClick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.className === 'item') {
    // do smth
    }
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921413/difference-between-e-target-and-e-currenttarget) answer to see the difference between event.currentTarget and event.target .